# Function with two preimages per y

Tags: analysis, continuity

I am searching for a function f: R -> R which has exactly two preimages for **every** y.
I was thinking about stuff like `x^2` but this function doesn’t have preimages for y<0 and furthermore, there is just one preimages for y=0.

So I came to the idea, that a function like that cannot be continuous (might be an interesting thing to prove that).

Does anyone have a nice example for a function f like that?

Comment: For the continuous case see, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848202/show-that-theres-no-continuous-function-that-takes-each-of-its-values-fx-ex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this $f$ will not be continuous.

Define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x-k$ if $2k-1<x\leq 2k+1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

[image]

This function also happens to be surjective.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a bijection $f_1 : (-\infty, 0) \to \mathbb R$ and a bijection $f_2 : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$. Define 
$$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
f_1(x) & \mbox{ if  } x < 0 \\
f_2(x)& \mbox{ if  } x  \geq 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.$$