# Show that a continuous function doesn't exist such that for every real $c$, there exist exactly two reals $a, b$ s.t. $f(a)=f(b)=c$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I got pretty confused at that question... Can anyone help me understand this question better and/or drop some hints please? Thank you!

Comment: There's something wrong here.  It seems like a constant function is a pretty obvious counterexample to the claim in the title.

Comment: $x^2$ doesn't work because you have $0$ in the range but only real gets mapped to $0$.

Comment: @RobertShore: the title (possibly after an edit) says *exactly* two, so that counterexample won't work (anymore).

Comment: How much background do you have?  Can you use that continuous functions always achieve their minimum and maximum on a closed and bounded interval?

Comment: I would suggest that you try drawing pictures and see what stops you from succeeding in finding such a function. Then see what theorems might be relevant to prove that is impossible, based on your experimentation with the pictures.

Comment: @Robert Shore op said for exactly two reals $a,b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=c$,you can't go for constant function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that there's no continuous function that takes each of its values $f(x)$ exactly twice.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848202/show-that-theres-no-continuous-function-that-takes-each-of-its-values-fx-ex)

Comment: @Subhajit It said that after an edit.

Comment: This isn't exactly a duplicate.  The linked question merely has $f$ defined on a closed interval and the proof used that fact.  This question assumes it's defined on all of $\Bbb R$.